# Como logro capturar el evento cuando se modifica un EditText?

Tags: eventos, edittext

Necesito capturar el evento de un EditText para borrar los resultados que muestro en pantalla.

Comment: Hola Raúl, te invito a leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Además sería de gran ayuda para aquellos dispuestos a ayudarte que nos brindes un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). :-)

Comment: De acuerdo. Son mis primeros pasos en stackoverflow. Slds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu pregunta no es muy explicita pero si estamos hablando de android puedes capturar el evento de cambio de texto así:

```
EditText textValue = ....

    textValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    //System.out.println(s.toString() + " " + start + " " + count + " " + after);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    //System.out.println(s.toString() + " " + start + " " + count);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    //System.out.println(s.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Anduvo. Fué escueta mi pregunta pero a buen entendedor pocas palabras dice el dicho. Abrazo !